# need help for css div

Tags: css, html

Body properties such as different font works but div tag properties like in `#mainpic` or `#header` just don't work

```css
body {
  font-family: Callibri, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  #mainpic {
    <img src="../image/cutmypic.png";
    alt="image not found";
    />background-position: "centre";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    center: 0;
  }
}

#header {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Introduction</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/newcss.css" />
</head>

<body background="image/bg.jpg">

  <div id=“ container”>
    <div id=“ header”>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpic"></div>
    <div id=“ content”>/div>
      <div id=“ navigation”> a link to the other web page</div>

      <div id=“ footer”> contains your name and student number</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No need to shout. Also you have a typo here `<div id   =  “content”>/div>` Also use the `<>` snippet editor and remove the HTML from your CSS

Comment: `#mainpic{
    <img src="../image/cutmypic.png"; alt="image not found";/>` you can't use HTML tags inside CSS rules.

Comment: 1) Please could you remove caps-lock as it's very difficult to read. 2) That image html tag doesn't belong in css.

Comment: You have extra spacing that shouldn't be there such as `div id=“ header”` and also notice the double quotes in that string are curly quotes like from Word. Use proper straight quotes like `div id="header"`. What are you using to write HTML? You should use a proper text editor/ide like Atom, VSCode, WebStorm, etc.

Comment: You can't use nested selectors in vanilla css either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first up: use classes not IDs. Good css never has any ids in it (except for some very very specific cases)

Secondly, you got html in your css, so that does not work.

Thirdly, you cannot nest css selectors. Instead of

```
.wrapper {
  /* some css */
  .element {
    /* some css */
  }
}
```

you have to write

```
.wrapper {
  /* wrapper css */
}
.wrapper .element {
  /* element css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close all brackets properly in the CSS code, move the `img` tag from the CSS to the HTML code and don't use invalid properties or values ("centre", "center") in your CSS.

Also, you are using lots of typographical quotes in your codes. You have to replace all these with regular quotes - it won't work otherwise.

```css
body {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#mainpic {
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#header {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Introduction</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/newcss.css" />
</head>

<body background="image/bg.jpg">

  <div id=“ container”>
    <div id=“ header”>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpic"><img src="../image/cutmypic.png" ; alt="image not found" ; /></div>
    <div id=“ content”></div>
      <div id=“ navigation”> a link to the other web page</div>

      <div id=“ footer”> contains your name and student number</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but I still can't see my header font in white neither can I see the image for mainpic

Comment: to be frank: Your code is a complete mess, you really have to clean it up. One thing I haven't mentioned/seen before: You are using lots of typographical quotes in your codes. You have to replace all these with regular quotes.

Comment: oh lol thank you so much , im pretty much new to html , our professor told us to use those typographical quotes but they were the goddamn problem.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  font-family: Callibri, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#mainpic {
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /*center:0;*/
}

#header {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body background="image/bg.jpg">

  <div id=“container”>
    <div id=“header”>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpic"></div>
    <div id=“content”></div>
    <div id=“navigation”> a link to the other web page</div>
    <div id=“footer”> contains your name and student number</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The 1st your problem is that you have several typos. 
For example, `<div id = “content”>/div>`.

The 2nd problem is that you can not use HTML tag in CSS.

The 3rd problem is that there is no syntax `center` in CSS.

And when you use `background-position`, you don't need to use `" "` , and you should write `center` NOT `centre`.

Comment: Please explain what you changed

Comment: @mplungjan I will.

Comment: @mplungjan I explained. but I'm not good at English, so you may not understand what I want to say.